# Can't bind many to many field correctly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have 2 models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    """
    model for tag
    """
    # name of tag
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="tag name", unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Note(models.Model):
    """
    model for note
    """
    # date of publication note
    publication_date = models.DateField("Publication date", auto_now_add=True)
    # date of last change
    date_last_change = models.DateField("Last changed", auto_now=True)
    # note title
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Note title")
    # main text of note
    main_text = models.TextField("Note text")
    # tags
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='Tags')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

As you see, one note has many tags, and one tag is related to many notes. But when I started to fill data in admin panel, I noticed that when I add a tag in note it automatically binds to all notes. Even if I add tag with Tag menu in admin panel it also binds to all notes.
I already tried manually adding model like NoteTag with foreign keys to Note and Tag but have the same issue. I still new in django and little bit confused by this situation.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Is it possible you've get confused by default django `ManyToManyField` widget showing all related records?

Comment: I should check it with django shell, right?

Comment: Yes this way. Do you know how to do it? In case 'not':

`note = Note.objects.get(id=1)
note.tags.all()`

will show all note tags

Comment: Thank you very much, I just realize how this widget works. It displays all available tags and I shoul choose which I want with CTRL key. You right, this is very confusing. Can I tweak this widget somehow in admin.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about this? Is it possible you've get confused by default django ManyToManyField widget showing all related records?

Try to check it with shell this way:

```
note = Note.objects.get(id=1)
note.tags.all()
```

will print all note tags.

And you can tweak widgets with third-party apps (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks/1.3) But i guess this is not so simple :)